How to run tests that are skipped or excluded by config?
I have a test suite where some tests are really slow, so I tagged them as such:
# tests_1.robot
TEST-1
    [Tags]  slow
    (...)

In order to avoid the time penalty each time I launch the tests, such tags are excluded from ’normal’ executions by using the Robot config file:
# robot-arguments.cfg
(... other various settings ...)
--exclude slow

This test is skipped (i.e. not present) when running robot in command-line, which is fine:
$ robot --argumentfile robot-arguments.cfg -t "TEST*" tests/
[ ERROR ] Suite 'Tests' contains no tests or tasks matching name 'TEST*' and not matching tag 'slow'.


Now, regularly I want to run this test anyway, so I tried --include argument:
$ robot --argumentfile robot-arguments.cfg -t "TEST*" tests/ --include slow
[ ERROR ] Suite 'Tests' contains no tests or tasks matching name 'TEST*' and matching tag 'slow' and not matching tag 'slow'.

So no test is run, which is not described by the message no tests matching tag 'slow' and NOT matching tag 'slow' (emphasis mine).
This is not desired; also, I do not want to remove the line from the config file, as it is used elsewhere.
Is there any way to overload the arguments passed by configuration with the arguments passed in command-line?
I could find nothing about this in the documentation. The situation is the same if I use --skip slow in Robot config file.

{EDIT} I tried to read RobotFramework code base on this, but the project is too deeply structured for my knowledge, with lots of composition and inheritance, and I lost track several times trying to understand how a precedence/priority between settings occurs.

No there is no immediate solution, other than not using that argument file.
Since you are in a shell, you can prepare a different argument file for your case. For example:
sed 's/exclude slow/include slow/g' robot-arguments.cfg > slow-robot-arguments.cfg && robot --argumentfile slow-robot-arguments.cfg -t "TEST*" tests/


Thanks for the answer, that's a way I may be forced to follow. I think I will fill in a feature request, that presents the need for precedence between arguments.
